# Angular ngif rules disable checkbox

Tags: angular

I am looking for the best way to disable checkbox base off of an bool ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
  <input 
    id="cb_note_{{note.Id}}" 
    type="checkbox" 
    (change)="toggleNoteState(note)" 
    [checked]="isNoteChecked(note)">
  <label attr.for="cb_note_{{note.Id}}"></label>
</div>
```

trying something like but it didnt work the edit text and checkbox is still able to be uncheck.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
input id="cb_note_{{note.Id}}" type="checkbox" 
(change)="toggleNoteState(note)" 
[checked]="isNoteChecked(note)"
[disabled]="readOnlyStyleGuideNotes">
<label attr.for="cb_note_{{note.Id}}"></label>
</div>
```

[image: Checkbox UI]

[image: Can see the value being set]

ts code

```
private readOnlyStyleGuideNotes: boolean; 


        ngOnInit() {
            this.readOnlyStyleGuideNotes = this.context.readOnlyStyleGuideNotes();
        }


     public readOnlyStyleGuideNotes(): boolean {
            return this.getContext().ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just make small correction in html. Change ng-disabled to disabled and use this disabled property in checkbox not in label.

```
<input id="cb_note_{{note.Id}}" type="checkbox" 
(change)="toggleNoteState(note)" 
[disabled]="ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes" 
[checked]="isNoteChecked(note)">
```

Below are changes made -

1. Added the property `[disabled]`
2. Changed `ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes == 'True'` to `ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes`
3. Remove the `ng-disabled` from the label.

Answer (score 0):

You've disabled your text.  If you want it hidden use `[hidden]="ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes"`.  Alternatively if you want it removed completely from the DOM use `*ngIf="!ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes"`

`<label attr.for="cb_note_{{note.Id}}" *ngIf="!ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes"></label>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a mixture of AngularJS(1.x) and Angular(2+) syntax. `ng-disabled` is a directive on AngularJS. So it won't be available for use on Angular.

Also, you can't make a `label` tag disabled. It only works with `input` tags.

Finally since `ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes` is a `boolean`, you can simply use `[disabled]="ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes"` to make the input disabled.

```
<input 
  id="cb_note_{{note.Id}}" 
  type="checkbox" 
  (change)="toggleNoteState(note)" 
  [checked]="isNoteChecked(note)"
  [disabled]="ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes">
```

I'm pretty sure this won't be needed. But just in case, here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disabled-checkbox?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I did try that can it be something related to the ngOnInit()?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: I did try [disabled]="readOnlyStyleGuideNotes" but it didnt work I can see that the value is set to true.

Comment: @Jefferson, even if it's in ngOnInit, it should eventually disable the checkbox. You might want to consider creating a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue if you want more help.